# Postman vs. Guzzle. How can I figure out the differences between same request sent with those 2 tools?

Tags: rest, postman, firebird, guzzle

So I'm working on a Laravel application that uses GuzzleHttp to consume an API. 
This API is coded with Delphi and connects to a Firebird DB.

We (the API team and my team) have found that when the web app consumes any given method of this API, the Firebird process (in the computer the API is running in) raises CPU usage up to 70-100% (and it also consumes a lot more memory). However, when we make the exact same request through Postman, Firebird only reaches about 20-35% of CPU usage and I have absolutely no idea why is that, so I need to figure out the differences between an API call from Guzzle and an "identical" one from Postman. Perhaps some deafult settings, headers, etc., are making this weird case possible.

<strike>*Perhaps it's worth noting that when we run the same queries that this method employs through Ibexpert or any other desktop (Delphi) app, CPU usage by Firebird only reaches roughly 9-12%.*</strike>

Question is: how can I tell the difference between a request being sent with Postman and one being sent with Guzzle?

Comment: This is impossible to answer with the information provided. You will need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. Normally I wouldn't expect identical requests to behave differently, and I certainly wouldn't expect that to impact the database in this way. Use a tool like wireshark to record the actual HTTP request and response, and see how they differ.

Comment: If you use FB 2.5 or later you can use TraceAPI to see which requests are going to Firebird. There is a number of commercial tools, free commandline tool is part of FB installation, and free simplistic GUI logger FBProfiler on SourceForge. One of the first things i'd suspect is the Delphi app failing to close transactions which should lead to OIT/OAT gap growing and garbage collection inhibited. But that is just speculation. Spikes in RAM+CPU use seems to me as after-the-fact sorting of large data rowsets, when indices couldn't be used before selecting for pre-ordered fetching. Speculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you.
@Arioch'The, I found your pointers very interesting and potentially helpful.
Although, maybe it's just how I phrased it but my question is how can I tell the differences between a request sent by Postman and one sent by Guzzle. I did not (and still do not) expect an answer to why the API seems to be raising CPU usage. Just how to tell the difference... I'll edit my question to better express this. But thank you anyway, I do find your comments useful.

Comment: Also, the API team seems to have solved the _real_ issue which was the high usage of CPU. But I still would really like to know what factors might make an API call from Postman different from one from Guzzle. I think it could also help someone out there...

Comment: Use wireshark to see the low-level network messages between the client and the server, or see if you can log the entire HTTP request server side.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thank you very much. I think that could be the best answer yet (to the actual question, that is). Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it as the one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see the low-level network messages between the client and the server, or see if you can log the entire HTTP request server side. That way you can find out the differences between the requests on a low-level.